# best real approximation to complex numbers

Tags: approximation

I have a system of equations and its answers are complex, but I want real numbers. Is there any way to find the best real approximation to a complex number?

Comment: What exactly are these "equations" you have? Anyway, if the imaginary parts are huge enough, well...

Comment: "Best" in what sense?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers ,My questions are: A^2=Alpha,B^2=Beta+2*a,C^2=Lambda Where Alpha=2.894812656849533, Beta=-2.159105950538185, Lambda=-0.003583679988243 I need A, B ,C to be best real numbers with a acceptable error to the true ones I will appreciate if you help me

Comment: Why do you need your results to be real? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: for those numbers, I get $A=1.7014148985035$, $B=1.1152236755327$. Only $C$ remains complex (actually, purely imaginary: $C=0.059863845418107\,i$).

Answer (score 3):

The best real approximation to a complex number is its projection onto the real axis, that is, its real part.

Comment: It depends on what you want to use it for: perhaps its magnitude might be more useful in some cases.

Comment: I meant *best* in the Euclidean sense, that is, the real number closest to a given complex number. And that is its real part.

Comment: @Ihf Could you please give some references defending this kind of approximation of complex numbers by its real part in euclidean sense if you have some ?

Comment: @optimalcontrol, it's the standard approximation in inner product vector spaces by orthogonal projection onto a subspace.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [Bairstow's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairstow%27s_method), which allows you to use real approximation techniques to locate the complex conjugate pairs of roots to real polynomials of arbitrary degree.

Effectively one applies a Newton method to find a real quadratic factor of the given real polynomial.

Perhaps a fuller description of your "system of equations" would be helpful.

**Added:**  In response to the system of equations added as a comment (3 times), it seems strange that you ask this.  As stated the equation for C is not related to the equations involving A and B, so the "best" real value of C s.t. $C^2$ is negative would be zero.  There are of course two purely imaginary exact roots for C.  The situation for A and B is not much more complicated.  You have two possible exact real roots for $A = \pm \alpha ^ {1/2}$, and for each of these two exact roots for $B = \pm (\beta + 2a)^{1/2}$.  One wonders if $A$ and $a$ in your equation for B are meant to be the same value.  Otherwise you have quite forgotten to tell us anything about $a$.  Assuming it is $A$, then taking the positive root for $A$ allows us to overcome the negative value for $\beta$ and get two exact real roots for $B$.  If you take the negative real root for $A$, then obviously the exact roots for $B$ are both purely imaginary (so their closest real approximations would be zero).

I won't go into a lot more detail (all that is required is taking some square roots), but I await your clarification of my suspicion that the equation for C is not complete as given.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers  ,My questions are:
 A^2=Alpha,B^2=Beta+2*a,C^2=Lambda
Where Alpha=2.894812656849533, Beta=-2.159105950538185, Lambda=-0.003583679988243
I need A, B ,C to be best real numbers with a acceptable error to the true ones
I will appreciate if you help me